# how do I get the program to keep entering the while loop?

Tags: java

Write a method named makeGuesses that will guess numbers between 1 and 50 inclusive until it makes a guess of at least 48. It should report each guess and at the end should report the total number of guesses made. Below is a sample execution:

```
 guess = 43
 guess = 47
 guess = 45
 guess = 27
 guess = 49
 total guesses = 5
```

THIS IS MY CODE SO FAR:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Guesses 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    int i = -1;
    int count = 0;
       if (!(i >= 1 && i <= 50))
       { 
        System.out.print("guesses = ");
        i = r.nextInt(50)+1;
        System.out.println(i);
        count++;
       }

     System.out.println("total guesses = "+ count);
    }
}
```

BUT ITS ONLY GUESSING ONCE AND NOT CONTINUALLY GUESSING?
SO FAR MY OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THIS:

```
guesses = 36
total guesses = 1
```

OR

```
guesses = 23
total guesses = 1
```

Its only guessing once.

Comment: There is no loop you have defined to iterate till 48 occurrence, and after the loop also change the if condition currently it returns false when i=23 or i=36

Comment: @Shivam No, I want it the program to keep guessing random numbers so it looks like the prompt's output. it should keep guessing until it guesses a number over 50... I just used 36 and 23 at random to show what I'm currently getting as my output.

Answer (score 0):

this part of code

```
if (!(i >= 1 && i <= 50)) { 
    System.out.print("guesses = "); 
    i = r.nextInt(50)+1; 
    System.out.println(i); 
    count++; 
}
```

is an If statment, not a loop. that's why it enter it only once. add the while loop before it or replace if by while or whatever you need

Comment: I've tested it with while, but continues to only produce one guess as the output.

Comment: what is the loop condition? please edit your question with the while loop so I can help you

Comment: The program should guess numbers between 1 and 50 inclusive until it makes a guess of at least 48. It should report each guess and at the end should report the total number of guesses made. I've been told to define that it has to be atleast 48, but I'm not sure how or where i should insert that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
public static void guessCounter() {
    int maxNr = 50;
    int upperLimit = 48;
    int totalGuesses = 0;
    int currGuess;
    Random r = new Random();
    do {
        currGuess = r.nextInt(maxNr) + 1;
        System.out.println("guess = " + currGuess);
        totalGuesses++;
    } while (currGuess < upperLimit);
    System.out.println("total guesses = " + totalGuesses);
}
```